# Golden Ratio Approximation

Tags: approximation, golden-ratio

$$\sqrt{1000}-30.0047 \approx \varphi $$
$$[(\sqrt{1000}-30.0047)^2-(\sqrt{1000}-30.0047)]^{5050.3535}\approx \varphi $$
Simplifying Above expression we get
$$1.0000952872327798^{5050.3535}=1.1618033..... $$
Is this really true that 
$$[\varphi^2-\varphi]^{5050.3535}=\varphi $$

Comment: FWIW, among the 10000 4-digit numbers, there are 10 (namely, 0000-9999) that are invalid inputs to the Kaprekar process for 4-digit numbers. This leaves 9990 valid inputs. If you divide that by Kaprekar’s constant for 4-digit numbers, namely, 6174, that is, you calculate the quotient 9990/6174, you get the golden ratio correct to 4 decimal places. Taking the reciprocal point of view, we can say that 6174 is the silver ratio deep within the valid inputs (not to be confused with the silver mean, also called the silver ratio).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*This is not an answer but it is too long for a comment.*

Working with illimited precision, let $$a=\sqrt{1000}-\frac{300047}{10000}\approx 1.6180766016837933200$$ $$(a^2-a)^{\frac {50503535}{10000}}\approx 1.6180331121536741389$$ $$\phi\approx 1.6180339887498948482$$ Using as exponent $5050.3592$ (same number of digits as in your post) instead (and doing the same), you would get  $$(a^2-a)^{\frac {50503592}{10000}}\approx 1.6180339909260630347$$ which is closer but still not exact (Vincenzo Oliva clearly explained the problem).

Comment: $$(a^2-a)^{5050.5}=1.618055698296593 $$                                                                
$$1.618055698296593^2-1.618055698296593=1.000048544493482191 $$ $$ 1.000048544493482191^{9913.03}=1.618033204292053595188$$ So Golden ratio is always Unique

Comment: @RAM. For sure, it is unique ! And we are lucky of that ! Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

No, not at all. Factoring and then using a well known property of $\varphi$: $$\left(\varphi(\varphi-1)\right)^{5050.3535}=\left(\frac{\varphi}{\varphi}\right)^{5050.3535}=1\ne\varphi. $$

The argument needs to be a bit larger than $1$. You're dealing with an approximation.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, this is an approximation. No need for more proof than those already given by Vincenzo Oliva and Claude Leibovici - kindest regards !

I would add that it is easy to find a lot of such approximations.

Some amazing ones, to be compared to :

$1.6180339887...\simeq\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}=\varphi$

$1.6180339886...\simeq\cos (\sqrt2\: e^{-2})-\cos(\sqrt[3]{2}\:e^\pi )$

$1.6180339884...\simeq\sqrt{\cosh(\gamma)+\cos(\gamma)}-\frac{\gamma^3}{\sin(5)}$ where $\gamma$ is the Euler constant.

$1.6180339881...\simeq\cosh(G^2\sinh(1))+\cos\left(\frac{\sqrt[3]\pi}{\cos(3)} \right)$ where $G$ is the Catalan constant.

They comes from : https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14161596/Mathematiques-experimentales  (page 4)

This paper roughly explains the method to compute a lot of approximations of this kind (In French, presently no translation avalable).